# Python - Accessing sys.stdin from within a class does not work

Tags: python, multiprocessing, stdin

So I am trying to read piped input from sys.stdin inside a class. The problem is that I am not getting any input from stdin while inside the class but I can get all the data from outside the class in main().

**Is there a way to access sys.stdin from within a multiprocessing class ?**

Here is my code:

```
class BufferReader(Process):

    def __init__(self, queue, lock):
        super(BufferReader, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        # number of lines to store in buffer before sending to processes
        self.buffer_size = 200000
        self.lines_buffer = []
        self.lock = lock

    def run(self):
        count = 0
        try:
            # for each line in the stdin
            for line in sys.stdin:
                # strip the line from any whitespace
                stripped = line.strip()

                # if end of line, break
                if not stripped:
                    break

                # add the line to the buffer
                self.lines_buffer.append(stripped)

                # if the buffer is full, process the data, and empty the buffer
                if count == self.buffer_size:
                    self.lock.acquire()
                    self.queue.put(self.lines_buffer)
                    self.lock.release()
                    del self.lines_buffer[:]
                    count = 0

                # increase the line counter
                count += 1
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.stdout.flush()
            pass

def parse(index, data_queue, lock):

    while not data_queue.empty():
        lock.acquire()
        if data_queue.empty():
            lock.release()
            sys.exit(0)
        result = data_queue.get()
        lock.release()

        with codecs.open("proc-%d" % index, 'w', 'utf-8') as fp:
            for line in result:
                fp.write(line)
            fp.close()
        sys.exit(0)

def main():
    data_queue = Queue()
    lock = Lock()
    br = BufferReader(data_queue, lock)
    br.start()

    # spawn the processes
    procs = [Process(target=parse, args=(i, data_queue, lock))
             for i in range(5)]

    for p in procs:
        p.start()

    br.join()

    for p in procs:
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why do you spawn 5 processes and then immediately lock up 4 of them?

Comment: br.start() is right under br = BufferReader(data_queue, lock). Also I lock them because I need to read from the queue one after the other. If I do not lock, it can cause problems due to multiprocessing.

Comment: What do you gain from doing this in parallel?

Comment: The BufferReader thread will be reading a ton of data and it will be buffering the stdinand putting the data on the queue for the processes to process, while the master(the one that spawned all) will be collecting results from each process and then save them to a file, while the other processes are doing their thing.

Comment: I'm not sure what your `sys.stdin`-related issue is, but I don't see the point in using more than one extra process if they're just going to wait around until they get access to the lock. It seems like only 1 will ever be doing anything useful.

Comment: The processes that read the data from the queue, will actually be performing data manipulation that takes time. Also, it will be a continuous loop until the queue is finally empty. The idea is to keep processing stdin data asynchronously, since each process will be working for some time on each data set.

Comment: I read your description of your issue, I just don't know how to solve it. That happens sometimes. I'm sorry for trying to help you with your code, I'll know better in the future.

Comment: @PatrickCollins, my bad. I understood your first line as if you said that my issue is not described well and it is not easily understood what the problem is at all in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

With [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) you spawn the workers in separate processes, with their own process IDs  and such including their own input and output devices. That means that the `sys.stdin/stdout` instance you obtain inside the spawned process will not be the same as that of the master process, although you can still read and write them.

There are at least two options of how to go about this:

- Pass a [`sys.stdin/stdout.fileno()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.IOBase.fileno) file descriptor of the master process down to the spawned processes. You should be able to open it inside the spawned processes using [`os.fdopen(fileno)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fdopen).
- Use [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) instead, as threads of the same process share input and output devices.

Also, as pointed out in the comments below, reading a single input stream concurrently from multiple processes may be tricky, if you don't know exactly what you are doing. It would be wise to designate only one process to read the input and dispatch the data to other workers. Or introduce some kind of round-robin system that will ensure only one of the processes at a time will grab the input data. Process pooling using [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) may come in handy for this.

And I'd recommend using [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module to make rading standard input easier.

Comment: Passing `sys.stdin` to the child process won't work; the file descriptor will be closed in the child.

Comment: @dano If you pass down a `sys.stdin.fileno()` file descriptor of the master process you should be able to open it using `os.fdopen(fileno)` in the spawned process.

Comment: Yep, but that's not actually what you said in the answer. You should edit that in.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this method only works if you don't read from stdin in the parent process prior to passing the file descriptor to the child (at least in my testing).

Comment: @dano Agreed, added and improved.

Comment: @dano Concurrent reading from the same stream may be dangerous indeed. Depends on what the program should be doing. And as I look at OP's process implementation I better add this to the answer.